# Let $(R, +, \cdot)$ be a ring. Show that if $(R, \cdot)$ is a group, then the ring only contains one element namely zero.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $(R, +, \cdot)$ be a ring. Show that if $(R, \cdot)$ is a group, then the ring only contains one element namely zero.

This seems to be due to the fact that the real numbers don't define a group under multiplication since the zero has no inverse? So $(R, \cdot) = \{0\} \implies (R, +, \cdot) = \{0\}$? Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: The statement seems to be about rings in general. Yet your reasoning is about the real numbers in particular. Is your $R$ only the real numbers?

Comment: Ah I see. I'm not entirely sure actually. It was written in the book like this and not $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Combine $r\cdot 0 = 0$ with the existence of multiplicative inverse for $0$

Comment: This has nothing to do with real numbers. Rings are often denoted by $R$. (not $\mathbb{R}$)

Comment: The universal notation for the real numbers in Western literature is the capital "R" in blackboard font $\Bbb R$ (simple bold $\bf R$ is also used and sometimes, I think mainly in old textbooks, an $\mathfrak R$ pops out). In general, you should not expect plain $R$ to mean the real numbers unless there is a reason for it, for instance: a) it's been stated in the text or b) the entire book or course is about real calculus, and I would say that the polite author should have this case fall under (a) as well.

Comment: Though I can see the nuance being subtle, if you have been born and raised in Japan.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is correct, although you should look at a general ring and not the ring of reals.

A ring is an abelian group with respect to addition. This means that the additive identity has the following property
$$r \cdot 0 = r \cdot (0 + 0) = r \cdot 0 + r \cdot 0 \implies r \cdot 0 = 0$$
Which is the property you mentioned of the reals. After that you correctly concluded that the ring needs to be zero for the group axioms to be fulfilled.